# Install a split MSI setup silently

Tags: delphi, windows-installer

I have to setup my application silently. I have created a **MSI** setup with Advanced Installer and Installshield but my problem is when my application size is bigger than one disk (DVD) and I split it to 2 or more.

I'm using Delphi to wrap MSI and get return codes from it, but in silent mode after the end of first disk the MSI returns **1602** code!

How can I get **1302** code from MSI, that means `Please insert the disk: [2]`?

This is my code to run MSI:

```
Result := FileExecute(handle, PChar(GetcurrentDir + '\' + setupFile),
    PChar(Format('/qn INSTALLDIR="%s" APPDIR="%s"  /l*v c:\temp\msi.log', [path, path])), '',
    SW_SHOWNORMAL, True);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Result));
```

Comment: What are these disks? Are you still using floppies? ;-)

Comment: :)) I Have 3-20 GB setups that splits in 1 to 5 DVDs

Comment: 1602 means "user cancelled installation", since the `/qn` switch is silent and non-interactive (with no UI). try other `/q` options such as `qr`. ([Command-Line Switches for the Microsoft Windows Installer Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/227091))

Comment: 20 GB of .msi??? I would rather install the executable and configuration with the .msi, but let the most content within external files, to be installed by the main executable, which may be run by the .msi itself. As such, you will be able to tune the installation process just as wanted, and allow other kind of installation (like streaming from Internet or local network).

Comment: @kobik, But I don't want show any dialog! I expect the msi return me 1302 code, but it close with 1602 code!!!

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, No 20 GB of .msi, the whole of my setup maybe enlarge to 20 GB.

Comment: How do you expect MSI to prompt for "Please insert the disk [2]"? You do realize that MSI process is responsible for this?

Comment: In [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx) Microsoft says that **1302** return code is `Please insert the disk [2]`. So we expect to get this message when one disk installation is complete and other disk is required. Just like other installers shows.

Comment: You can't have a "silent install" (no user interaction) if you also need to "prompt the user for disk 2". If you think about it, it should be very clear why: they're directly conflicting requirements. You can't do both at the same time.

Comment: I test `/qr` and full UI, but I still have my problem. There is no **1302** code!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two versions of the .msi. One version you deliver on multiple DVDs. You cannot possibly install that silently because you cannot silently change physical media. And the second version you deliver as a single, unsplit, package. That version has no problem being installed silently because there is no need for human intervention to change media.

Comment: Thanks, But what about `MsiSetExternalUI`? Is that can return **1302** code?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all of the files from all of the DVD's into a single folder on the system and then run your command.  Instead of prompting for another disc, it'll find the cab and keep on going.

Comment: But I want to install it from DVD-Rom